# Open url remotely

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube

Let's say I want to create a nodejs app that when I open a url it can opens and plays youtube url videos remotely over the local network.

To be more specific:

**Pc host (Who send):** Paste youtube url into web interface or even node console?

**Wiiu browser (Who recive):** With a web open that has an iframe? Or some way to get the url sent and is showed into?

It is possible? Where can I get some direction on how to do this?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it easy? No. [This project](https://github.com/DonaldDerek/PiR.tv) was built to do that but run it on a Raspberry Pi. The critical parts (loading the video, connecting to a running page, etc.) are all there. It's too big of a project to address on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MikeC It seems pretty simple to me? Just point the wii browser at the network ip and port and have it send out an event message to all connections when the url updates?

Comment: @zfrisch Sure, that's simple if you're comfortable with WebSockets. I could be wrong but I get the feeling OP is not at that level yet. I suppose it isn't *hard* like writing a compiler or your own server from the ground up but I'd call it an novice-to-intermediate project.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* route I can think of to doing this would be this:

1. Build a Node Server. It doesn't have to be anything special. Just something that opens up a port. You can write it in raw Node or use Express
2. Craft a web page that employs the Youtube API. You would need to sign up as a Developer on Google. It's free. This could be just as simple as an Iframe for the current video and links for others.

   - host this from your server.
3. Use Socket.io to develop management for peer connections. As in, when a link is clicked, trigger that event to be sent to all connected users. Write a function to change the currently viewing video in the frame.

Nothing is out of your league if you're willing to learn and put the effort in. Sans multiple connections I wrote one in React for a course a little while back. https://github.com/zfrisch/Youtube-React

**Resources:**

https://nodejs.org/api/ - Node Documentation

http://socket.io/ - Socket.io

https://developers.google.com/youtube/ - youtube API

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer you should say why. I feel like it's a perfectly reasonable answer given the question.

Comment: wow thanks, i appreciate it, i'll take a look to the resources, and well im just in an entry level of javascript so atm dont know react at all, although i'll take a look to your program to see what i can get. Regarding the answer when you said "Sans multiple connections" what it means? /edit/ i didnt downvote yout answer, dont have the level to vote yet :(

Comment: @JuanSebastianIlleraDuque It means that my React Youtube application isn't built to serve multiple connections with the same data. It's just an application that shows the Youtube api..